# Projectors which update their display output in raster fashion

Tags: displays, projector

I am looking to buy a projector that updates its display in a raster scan fashion. I was told by someone that this projector, [MP-CL1A mobile projector from Sony](https://www.sony.com/electronics/projector/mp-cl1a), does it.

My question is how do I identify projectors which work in this fashion? Which specification gives me information about the same? A few examples of models of would be appreciated.

Comment: I was under the impression that most projectors use some raster type graphics scheme. Out of curiosity have you found evidence to the contrary and why is this important to you?

Comment: I have a DLP lightcrafter module. I reached out to their support and they told me that the update doesn't happen in a raster fashion.  Apparently the update scheme in the lightcrafters are simultaneous(https://e2e.ti.com/support/dlp/f/94/t/791905). 
I assumed that all DLP based projectors in the market work in a similar fashion. I am confused if LCD projectors update the display in a raster fashion or not. I want a projector which updates in a raster fashion for an experiment.